# Возможно ли настроить webpack-dev-server, чтобы он открывал сразу несколько браузеров?

Tags: webpack-dev-server

Мне необходимо работать сразу с несколькими браузерами, чтобы видеть результат работы скрипта (скрипт меняет DOM, кое-что отрисовывает и т.п.).
webpack-dev-server у меня настроен, и по команде: `$ npm run server` открывается http://localhost:8080/ браузером, который установлен в системе по умолчанию и это понятно.

Но возможно ли настроить webpack-dev-server, чтобы он открывал сразу несколько браузеров, установленных в системе ? Может кто задавался таким вопросом?

Зачем?: Из-за особенностей скрипта и его работы, и в частности из-за некоторых отличий в парсинге DOM разных браузеров. (Использую так же task runner(build + watch), вот и хочется связать это для нескольких браузеров сразу).

Кто что может подсказать? Хотя бы примерно. (Ни в оф.документации ни поиск не помогли).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С плагином [`webpack-browser-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-browser-plugin) это возможно.

```
var plugins = [];

plugins.push(new WebpackBrowserPlugin({
  browser: 'Firefox',
  port: 9000,
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1'
}));
```

И в конфиг потом добавляете:

```
var config = {
  [...]
  plugins: plugins,
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Suvitruf, вот спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: @Алексей это радует ^_^